# Как отключить нажатия на экран во время работи прогресс бар

Tags: java, android, kotlin

У меня `RecyclerView` который загружает данные до того как он загружает я показываю прогресс бар, но во время показа я хочу чтобы нажатия на экран не сработал до того как не загрузятся все данные.

---

Здесь у меня isEnable кнопки а как быть с RV?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKqtn.png

Comment: Пробовали `setEnabled(false)` для RV?

Comment: да не помогло(((. Дело не в RV я просто хочу когда работает прогресс бар отключить все действие на этом фрагменте.

Comment: @Shahriyor, а как у вас прогрессБар реализован? Можно, например, его на прозрачном некликабельном фоне на весь экран показать поверх всего остального интерфейса или просто диалог отобразить. Проще - 1 вариант.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб у меня на весь экран но на заднем фоне видно RV вот я хочу чтобы экран был disable до того как прогресс бар станет Invisible вот мой прогресс бар

Comment: @Shahriyor, возможно вам надо просто `clickable="true"` (или false, не помню точно) поставить для контейнера, который перекрывает список и содержит прогресс бар?